# AngularJs returning data for multiple dynamic dropdowns

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm using angularjs with asp.net mvc.  On my page, I have 5 dropdown lists, all populated with values from different database tables.  In order to retrieve the data for all dropdowns, I'm making 5 different $http.get requests, which makes my page load time slow to a crawl.  I know this is setup wrong, but not sure how to do it properly.  Here's my angular code, which makes a call to an mvc action, returns the values for the dropdown & passes the results into the $scope, for the dropdown to display:

```
var CustomSearchController = function ($scope, $http) {    
$http.get('/Account/GetLists')
    .success(function (result) {
        $scope.listDetails = result;
    })        
 };
 $http.get('/Account/GetGenders')
    .success(function (result) {
        $scope.genderDetails = result;
    })        
 };
 $http.get('/Account/GetEthnicities')
    .success(function (result) {
        $scope.ethnicityDetails = result;
    })        
 };
 $http.get('/Account/GetRegions')
    .success(function (result) {
        $scope.regionDetails = result;
    })        
 };
 $http.get('/Account/GetAcademics')
    .success(function (result) {
        $scope.academicDetails = result;
    })        
 };
```

What's the correct way to go about this?

Comment: I cannot say this setup is wrong! . You can improve the load time by caching data in your server for these endpoints. Another option is to have a single endpoint which returns data for all 5 dropdowns in 5 different properties of the return object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`$httpProvider.useApplyAsync`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$httpProvider#useApplyAsync) and pass in `true`.

From the [`documentation`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$httpProvider#useApplyAsync):

> Configure $http service to combine processing of multiple http responses received at around the same time via $rootScope.$applyAsync. This can result in significant performance improvement for bigger applications that make many HTTP requests concurrently (common during application bootstrap).

This means that if true, when requests are loaded, they will schedule a deferred "apply" on the next tick, giving time for subsequent requests in a roughly ~10ms window to load and share the same digest cycle.

In short, you can avoid unnecessary digest cycles which *can* make a hell of a difference.

Simply pass `$httpProvider` into your run function and modify the provider like so:

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])

.run(function($httpProvider){

    $httpProvider.useApplyAsync(true);

});
```

Comment: No problem at all, there is nothing wrong with making separate requests. I have an application with around 40 similar requests and works perfectly :)

Comment: @Kildareflare did this answer help answer your question?

Comment: I was not the person who posted the question. Was just thanking you for making me aware of something I did not know :0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$q` service for such a scenario like this:

```
var CustomSearchController = function ($scope, $q, $log, $http) {
    var listPromise = $http.get('/Account/GetLists');
    var genderPromise = $http.get('/Account/GetGenders');

    var ethnicCitiesPromise = $http.get('/Account/GetEthnicities')

    var regionsPromise = $http.get('/Account/GetRegions')

    var academicPromise = $http.get('/Account/GetAcademics');

    $q.all([genderPromise, ethnicCitiesPromise, regionsPromise, academicPromise])
        .then(function (responses) {
            // Here you have all the resolved datas
            // responses[0]
            // responses[1]
            // responses[2]
            // responses[3]
        }).catch(function (error) {
            $log.error(error);
            throw error;
        })

}
```

However I prefer to call a function of `ng-change` of each dropdown to retrieve data in a cascade style.

Comment: How does `q` helps in this usecase ?  q is good to avoid callback tree hell.

Comment: @Shyju which hell do you mean? we've got ride of hell by using promises!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:
your Controller (main view):

```
ViewBag.regionDetailsJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(regionDetails );
```

In your view:

```
var regionDetailsJson = $.parseJSON('@Html.JsonRaw((string)ViewBag.regionDetailsJson )');
```

And than in your angular controller:

```
$scope.regionDetailsJson = regionDetailsJson;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using promises as suggested by HFA is a more Angular approach, but it will still result in 5 calls to the server; so will not really help improve your page load performance - i.e you will still be waiting for the 5 promises to resolve before you get your data.

One thing you could try is to formulate this lists when the page served by your MVC Account action is loaded and save these to the page model. You can then access this client side, in a script block, assigning them to a (global)variable, which you can then access in Angular.

I've not tested this but have you this approach in the past. As a guide the steps you would need to follow are:

In your AccountController

```
public ActionResulst Index() {
    var model = new AccountModel {
     Lists = GetLists(),
     Ethnicities = GetLists()
    }
  return View(model);
}
```

Then on your Razor Page

```
@model AccountModel
    <script>
        window.lists= "@(Model.Lists)";
        window.ethnicities = "@(Model.Ethnicities )";
    </script>
```

Then  in your Angular

```
var CustomSearchController = function ($window) { 

var lists = $window.lists;
var ethnicities  = $window.ethnicities;
}
```

You may need to convert the results to JSON using [JSON.Parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your approach. You are following the separation of concern, and single responsibility.

If you get the date from **Model** or **ViewModel** from ASP.Net MVC View, you cannot Unit Test the Angular Services easily.

Another approach is to use ***[resolve](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#components-as-route-templates)***. It basically load the data first before a route executes. ***FYI***: It will not improve the overall loading time, although you can display page loading icon.

[Demo for Angular 1.5 Route Resolve at Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FyXdSwISs31LgYactH8x?p=preview)

```js
(function () {

    angular
      .module("app", ['ngRoute'])
      .config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
          .when("/home", {
              template: `<main 
                promise-followers="$resolve.promiseFollowers"></main>`,
              resolve: {promiseFollowers: function ($http) {
                    return $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers")
                      .then(function(result) { 
                        return result.data;
                      }, function(result) { 
                        console.log(result);
                      });
                }
              },
          })
          .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/home" } );
      })
      .component("main", {
        template: `<h3>Demo Angular 1.5 Resolver</h3>
        
        <p>Promise Data from Resolve : 
          <select ng-model="$ctrl.selected" 
            ng-options="option.id as option.login for option in $ctrl.promiseFollowers"></select>
        </p>        
        
        <h4>Regular Selector Selected: {{$ctrl.selected}}</h4>`, 
        bindings: {
          promiseFollowers: '='
        },
        
        controller: function(){
          
        }
      });
      
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
  </body>

</html>
```